# CSS Instagram Image Box Layout

Tags: html, css, sass

I am making a Instagram layout provided below, basically, the image/boxes have aspect ratio of 1:1 (just diffrent sizes), I am using Bootstrap 4 and SCSS mixin for aspect ratio.

[image]

*My issue is I cannot align properly the 4 boxes surrounding the big box on the middle and the spacing on the middle box.*

I used absolute positioning and flexbox, something like below but I am not sure if this is the right approach.

```
.ig {
    &-wrapper {
      display: flex;
      align-items: flex-end;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    &-item-1,
    &-item-2 {
      width: 180px;
      height: 180px;
      @include aspect-ratio(180px, 180px);
    }
}
```

Here is the demo link to what I have started

https://codepen.io/johndavemanuel/pen/WNQgzZO

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Switch to bootstrap columns instead of flexbox

```
<div class="row ig-row-1">
        <div class="col-1 offset-3 ig-col">
          <div class="ig-row-1-item-1 bg-primary">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/600x600/?boxing" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <div class="ig-row-1-item-2 bg-primary">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/600x600/?boxing" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
          <div class="ig-row-1-item-3 bg-primary">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/600x600/?boxing" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

https://codepen.io/johndavemanuel0528/full/YzyOJvJ